# Why do hex code symbols render incorrectly in Outlook email templates and how can I fix it?

Tags: html, encoding, outlook, html-email, html-encode

I'm currently updating our email templates and experiencing an issue with hex code symbols rendering incorrectly in Outlook viewed on a browser, specifically Office 365 Chrome Windows 10, Office 365 Edge Windows 10. Office 365 Firefox Windows 10, and Outlook.com Chrome Windows 10.

Does anyone know a good trick for getting these to render correctly?

I'm specifically trying to add a copyright symbol to our email templates. When I use the `&copy;`, my usual go-to, it seems to insert a capital letter A with a circumflex accent (`&‌Acirc;`). Each potential variation on the copyright symbol seems to include an undesired non-English character before the symbol. I expanded beyond copyright and found this extended to any visible symbols I tried, but did not affect invisible HTML entitles like `&nbsp;`.

Please see the example in [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTT06.png)—this appears as `&copy; || &#169; || &#xA9; || &#9400; || &#x24B8; || &#9426; || &reg; || &trade; || &spades; || &clubs; || &hearts; || &diams; || &nbsp; || 2023` in my code.

Comment: Are you setting your own HTML? Does it include the correct charset in the header?

Comment: What system are you using? How are you copying them - or are you writing them? Can you share a larger snippet of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the UTF-8 character set.

Add this line into your `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Hm, I tried this, but it doesn't seem to be working.